# Image upload to server from sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm a beginner in sencha touch. I need to know how many ways its possible to send image from android-app to a server using sencha touch. Is any tutorial or example for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?142107-image-upload

Or here:

- http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/
- http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/25/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap/

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would share a non-phonegap solution that is still in its infancy... I tested it on my Nexus 7 using the latest version of Chrome (at the time of this writing) and it worked for me. https://github.com/kostysh/File-uploading-component-for-Sencha-Touch

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar file upload from an iOS app using [Phonegap FileTransfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer).  This will also work with Android.